# Rexster (Titan 0.5.1) is not showing default graph

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin, rexster

I've installed titan (0.5.1) from link 
[titan-0.5.1](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/titan-0.5.1-hadoop2.zip)
I ran command `sudo bin/titan.sh start` , Then I started bin/rexster-console.sh

> Then, I went to http://localhost:8182/graphs/ 
>   it is not showing default graph. graph list is coming as empty.

```
{
"version": "2.5.0",
"name": "Rexster: A Graph Server",
"graphs": [],
"queryTime": 3.082986,
"upTime": "0[d]:00[h]:00[m]:57[s]"
}
```

Can someone help me to create graph using Rexster.

Comment: And the script reported OK for Cassandra, Elasticsearch, Titan, and Rexter during startup? Any reason why you are not using the latest 0.5.x? I just tried with titan 0.5.4 and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried with titan 0.5.4 as well. it is giving empty list in graphs field. I'm using java 1.8 and using Amazon ec2 server. can you share the steps you tried.

Comment: The steps are as simple as they can get: download, unzip, run `./titan.sh start`. I started everything under my own non-root user.

Comment: Please check `titan-0.5.1-hadoop2/log/rexstitan.log` or any of the other log files for errors and edit your post with more details if you found some.